# Keep the current structure or create my own in a wordpress child theme?

Tags: wordpress

I am modifying the header.php of a wordpress child theme, what should I do here or what is more correct, keep the structure of the correct header.php or create my own?
I mean, preserve the current ids, classes and hierarchy or replace them for whatever I need?

Comment: If you are going to want to change anything from the parent header.php then create header.php in the child , copy the full code from the parent and make the changes..

Comment: It is what I have done, but now should I keep the #masthead, #navbar, #site-navigation or can I replace all them? What is better, keep the structure or not?

Comment: depends on your design..keep what you need and remove what you don't need

Comment: I think that removing all I don't need will take more time than add what I need but this will force me to restructure the site